# DLL on Production Server Throws Server Error, IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-server-error

I've been having problems with a site we have built in MVC5. It contains the standard mix of JS, CSS, jQuery, controllers, views and so on. The other day when we copied the DLL's to the live server, we got a generic server error message like this:-

https://sslproxy.getsatisfaction.com/sslproxy/SWhAdDNLMG5zdGFuVGlWenmLbJDGd3CABhjZermgcystANA4T6nd0pzV0fSzBRRGOd17A4b8ZLwi6-HESbXI0jZCKKXz14fzqyaK9srU32RZSu1EuPVb0ug2sk5zFhaRn-eVxTfQVKiEYo0BC-vdpQ==.jpg

It wasn't an IIS message, and the facility in Global.asax that we have to email us with the Exception details never came through. If we copy back the backed up DLL, the site works fine again.

I spent some time doing some digging and we tried various stuff, and eventually this addition in the web.config fixed the issue:-

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

I added the existingResponse="PassThrough" and the site with the DLL's that would orignally break, suddenly started working. But why? What does this existing response passthrough do and I am simply suppressing a bigger problem I'm not aware of?

Any information or suggestions would be fantastic!
Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31041696/894792

Answer (score 0):

I create a new site on IIS, and the problems with the DLL corruption were solved. I didn't need the change in the web.config in the end.